# what if Vlookup multiple values in excel

Tags: excel

i am beginner Excel , i want to do some on excel,
If lookup returns multiple values, I want count of values or if possible can give some color for that cell based on count,

`=INDEX($B$3:$C$7, SMALL(IF(($E$3=$B$3:$B$7), ROW($B$3:$B$7)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$7))+1, ""),ROWS($A$1:A1)), 2)`

Comment: when posting, please format your code. highlight the code, and then press **ctrl+k**

Comment: You will need curly braces if this is an array formula i.e.  {=INDEX($B$3:$C$7, SMALL(IF(($E$3=$B$3:$B$7), ROW($B$3:$B$7)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$7))+1, ""),ROWS($A$1:A1)), 2)}

Comment: As @QHarr said, above formula is an array formula so instead of just pressing `Enter` commit formula by pressing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` then drag/copy down. If you only want the count of `E3` in `B3:B7` use `=COUNTIF($B$3:$B$7,E3)`.

Comment: thanks Harr & Mrig,

Comment: can any one give me the syntax for vlookup to if get multiple matches pick min value and count of matches,